# How to unit test function that has an external function call using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have a function foo(par1) with an internal function call, (db_fetch) which is a database call using SQLAlchemy to get a stored value as below:

```
def foo(par1):
    db_value = db_fetch(par1)
    if db_value > 10:
        return db_value * 5
    else:
        return 1
```

I am currently creating a db pytest fixture and loading test data every time I run the test suite in order to provide data for the db_fetch function call. How can i convert the test to use dummy data for the db_fetch function call to speed up the test run?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: Where's `db_fetch` coming from? Patch it up, or even better: make it injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1- use dependency injection (change the way your function is defined, so that it is easier to test)

```
def foo(par1, fetch_function):
    db_value = fetch_function(par1)
    if db_value > 10:
        return db_value * 5
    else:
        return 1
```

In normal code, call it like this:

```
foo(my_par_1, db_fetch)
```

instead of:

```
foo(my_par1)
```

And in unit tests, call it like this:

```
foo(my_par_1, lambda par: 42)
```

And so, during the unit tests, the value will always be 42, instead of the real database value.

2- mock the call to fetch_function

In your unit test, instead of calling :

```
foo(my_par1)
```

You should call:

```
mock = MagicMock(return_value=42)
with patch('fetch_function', mock):
    foo(my_par1)
```

Instead of 'fetch_function', you may have to write 'my_module.fetch_function', if fetch_function is imported from a module.
See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html 
There are several ways of doing the mock, and several libraries that can do the job.

3- Make a pytest fixture so that every unit test is run on a test-specific memory database, that contains only test data.

This is more tricky to set up.

Comment: Thank you, I think I shall look into using mock, its looks more scalable than the other option. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is called stubbing the function and it is pretty easy in python.
The way you can achieve this is by:

```
def stub_foo():
    # some code without the DB stuff...
original_foo = foo
try:
   foo = stub_foo
   # some tests here with the stubbed function
finally:
   foo = original_foo
```